# FiWare CEP (Proton) doesn't response via REST

Tags: fiware, complex-event-processing, fiware-cep

I have some problems with CEP and I hope someone can help. I have a CEP instance in the FiWare Cloud, with the default setup. I have an event with 3 parameters, a temporal context which defines that starts at startup and never ends and nothing else special. If this event come in, CEP should response with a REST output. Everything worked fine for a few hours, but the next day it stopped working. Tried restart the server, and the definition as well.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

We need yo know your environment and the json description of your rules.
My hunch is that the server crashed due to memory overflow since contexts that do not end can exhaust the machine resources. Also, depending on the rate of events.
You can read more on the rules in the users guide:
http://proactive-technology-online.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ProtonUserGuide_FI_WAREv4_4_1/index.html
- Uri

Comment: I emailed you the json description before. I think it is not a memory related issue, because I sent a few events not frequently, and btw I restarted the server.

Comment: Hi Adam, I'm sorry, but best is to append this Json here to share with us. Secondly, it is not clear what you did when restarting, and why was it different from the original start which worked for a few hours.
Please clarify. Can you also share the server resources used?
Thanks.

Comment: Again - Adam, if you still have an issue here, please respond to my request above so we can help you. If that issue is resolved by now, please indicate so here.

Comment: Sorry for not responding. My JSON can be find here: [link](http://130.206.120.198:8080/ProtonOnWebServerAdmin/resources/definitions/PixPay). By restarting I meant first restart the Tomcat server, then reboot the cloud instance. My server configuration is: RAM: 2GB, CPU: 1 VCPU, Disk: 20 GB. I did nothing after it worked, just go home and the day after it won't work anymore. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The problem might be with the server itself or with the publishing of your input event as output to the RESTful service. 
I suggest the following : Proton publishes console output while initializing. The Tomcat's log file (catalina.log) should contain information re the initialization of Proton web application. It will also contain any kind of error messages. You should also see there if Proton receives any input events at all - they are printed out to the log as well.
Please share this log file. 
Additionally you can try something out- you can add a file consumer (example of how to do that can be found in Proton documentation), and see if the DiscountReport event gets published to that file. This will help determine if the problem might be with your RESTful consumer

Comment: Hi Adam - have you tried any of these? Any conclusions you can share with us?